# kubernetes django deployment with gunicorn

Tags: django, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy an empty image of alang/django using kubernetes on my minikube cluster.

This is my manifest file for deployment.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: django
  labels:
    app: django
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pod: django
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        pod: django
    spec:
      restartPolicy: "Always"
      containers:
      - name: django
        image: alang/django
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
        env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: postgresql-db-configmap
                  key: pg-username
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgresql-db-secret
                  key: pg-db-password
            - name: POSTGRES_HOST
              value: postgres-service
            - name: REDIS_HOST
              value: redis-service
            - name: GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS
              value: "--bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

but i am facing issues with deployment , i think with gunicorn, getting this back:

TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '.wsgi'

Any way please to deploy it correctly?

Comment: That error seems unrelated to the Kubernetes manifest you included.  Can you `docker run` the same image in a plain Docker setup?  Can you edit the question to include your image's Dockerfile and any other details required for a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick answer. I don't have any dockerfile created. i am deploying an empty app on the cluster.

Comment: To reiterate what @DavidMaze said: this error appears unrelated to Kubernetes. There is [documentation for that image](https://hub.docker.com/r/alang/django/) that may help you get started.